# Help solving differential equation in closed form - Damped Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve analytically, a differential equation of the form

$$ -\alpha \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \beta y \frac{dy}{dx} + \gamma x^2 y = (\epsilon )y$$

Where, $\alpha $ , $ \beta$, $\gamma$ and $ \epsilon$ are constants.

The inclusion of the second term has thrown a spanner in the works. I attempted using Frobenius method but am unable to formulate a recursion relation. I have the solution of the equation with the second term excluded, and it yields a solution that depends on a Hermite polynomial.

I am hoping the solution will incorporate that too. Let me know if you have any resources you can

Comment: Do you have any additional conditions on the problem? Such as initial or boundary conditions? Since this is a nonlinear ODE, there may be NO solution at all (though it looks like there probably is one in this case), or if there is, it may not be unique. Even in the unique case, the solution might not have an "elementary" closed form.

Comment: The function y must tend to 0, as |x| tends to infinity. I have solved this for the case where there is no second term (no first derivative) and it is the classic solution to a 1D harmonic oscillator. In it I have solutions that vary with an integer n, from the Hermite polynomial. Conveniently I also acquired eigen values $\epsilon_n$ that depend on the integer n, as I would expect for my quantised system

Comment: Ok, are you solving for a wavefunction? If so, we also know that all derivatives of y must decay to zero at infinity as well.

Comment: That's correct. I am solving for a wave function and that parameter does hold

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to obtain a "nice" solution. But if you're okay with approximation, you could use perturbation theory here, taking $\beta$ as a small parameter. Write $y$ as a combination of simpler functions:
$$
y(x) = y_0(x) + \beta y_1(x) + \beta^2 y_2(x) + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta^ky_k(x).
$$
A priori, this sum is formal--there is no reason it should converge in any sense (unless of course the series terminates). Substitute into the original ODE:
$$
-\alpha\sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta^k\frac{d^2y_k}{dx^2} + \beta\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\beta^ky_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\beta^k\frac{dy_k}{dx}\right)+ \gamma x^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta^ky_k = \epsilon \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta^ky_k.
$$
Equate coefficients according to powers of $\beta$. For example, looking at $\beta^0$ gives you the linear harmonic oscillator equation,
$$
-\alpha\frac{d^2y_0}{dx^2} + \gamma x^2y_0 = \epsilon y_0.
$$
You remarked that you already have the solution to this equation. Take that solution $y_0$ and examine the $\beta^1$ equation,
$$
-\alpha\beta\frac{d^2y_1}{dx^2} + \beta y_0\frac{dy_0}{dx} + \gamma x^2\beta y_1 = \epsilon\beta y_1 \implies -\alpha\frac{d^2y_1}{dx^2} + \gamma x^2y_1 = \epsilon y_1 + y_0\frac{dy_0}{dx}.
$$
We see that this equation is actually still linear in $y_1$ because we know $y_0$! In fact, it is just the same as the linear harmonic oscillator with the inhomogeneous term $y_0\frac{dy_0}{dx}$. In general, following this procedure gives that for the $\beta^k$ term, we have
$$
-\alpha\frac{d^2y_k}{dx^2} + \gamma x^2y_k = \epsilon y_k + f_k,
$$
where$f_k$ is a term depending only on $y_0, \cdots, y_{k-1}$ and their first derivatives (you could write a formula for $f_k$ using combinatorical methods). So now you can apply techniques of linear ODEs to solve the problem.

Again, there is no guarantee that this process terminates, or even that the sequence $y_k$ converges to the true solution $y$. But it may give you at least an idea of the asymptotic behavior of your true solution. Perhaps look at what the [ladder operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method) do to the $f_k$.